# Nodejs: Display POST data from another website

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, post, request

Im trying to figure it out for past 6 hours, but Im out of ideas..

What Im trying to accomplish:

I want to display a JSON data that looks like this

```
movie {title: " xxxxx", seed: "number", url: "zzzzzzzzz"}
```

I want to display it on my Node server(via jade), but what I accomplished till now is to send it from the website to my node server via POST request using this code:

**My JS script**

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://localhost:8080/";
var params = arr; <------ My JSON data
http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        console.log(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(params);
```

After using above code in my google chrome developer tools on the website I actually have that data, I receive the JSON array in my node, here is my node code:

**My app.js node server**

```
const http = require("http");
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const myParser = require('body-parser');


app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
app.set('view engine', 'jade')
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
app.use(myParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(myParser.json())

var allowCrossDomain = function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
}

app.use(allowCrossDomain);

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
})

app.get('/tl', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('tl');
})

app.post("/", function (req, res) {
  response = {
    first_name: req.body
  };

  console.log('SHOW ME BODY')
  console.log(req.body);

  res.send('You sent: this to Express');
});

app.listen(8080);
```

And this is what Im receiving in my node command prompt:

```
{ '[{"title":" SOME-MOVE-TITLE","seed":"NUMBER","url":"https://SOMEURLS.COM', etc. etc. etc.
```

**And finally here is my layout.jade file**

```
doctype
html
  head
    title Bolo Node Server
    link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css", href="stylesheet/style.css")
  body
    header
      h1 My Site
      block content
    footer
      p Running on node with Express, Jade and Stylus
```

**And index.jade**

```
extend layout

block content
  p= 'Block content works'
  script.
    if req.body != undefined
      div(id='data')= req.body
```

I really run out of ideas on how to display the json array Im receiving...help me out please

**Update**

My index.jade

extend layout

```
block content
  p= 'Block content works'
  div(id='data')
    pre
      test= jsonString
```

My app.js looks now like this:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
})

app.post("/", function (req, res) {
  // Get string representation
  var jsonString = JSON.stringify(req.body || {}); // use JSON.stringify(req.body || {}, null, 2) for formatted JSON
  console.log(jsonString);
  res.render('index', {test: jsonString});

  //res.send('You sent: this to Express');
});
```

I see the data in my node command prompt, but I dont see it on my local website http://localhost:8080/  the div(id='data') is showing me empty.. nothing, how do I get the jsonString there?? I want it to show me the data on my local website..

**

### UPDATE

**

I ended up just putting the data into the sqlite3 database and then retrieving the data via GET request and finally putting it into my jade template. I thought I can go around and not use sqlite3 but I couldnt figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

When you say that you want to display the json, if you just want to see the contents of the json you can use `res.json`.

```
app.post("/", function (req, res) {
  // Send back the request body if present or else, an empty object
  res.json(req.body || {});
});
```

If you want it to be displayed inside a template, you can get a string representation of the json using `JSON.stringify(req.body)` and render that in your template by passing it to it as a local variable.

```
app.post("/", function (req, res) {
  // Get string representation
  var jsonString = JSON.stringify(req.body || {}); // use JSON.stringify(req.body || {}, null, 2) for formatted JSON

  res.render('jsonView',{jsonString});
});
```

And in your template:

```
div(id='data')
  pre
    code = jsonString
```

Comment: When I paste your code the console shows me :
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Comment: For which solution? First or second? Usually this happens when `res.send` `res.json` are called multiple times. Check your muddleware which come before

Comment: Im trying the 1st solution and well, nothing happens?

For the second I don't know how do I show it in the template mate? Look at my app.post
`app.post("/", function (req, res) {
 
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(req.body || {}); // use 

JSON.stringify(req.body || {}, null, 2) for formatted JSON
 console.log(jsonString);
 res.render('tl', {test: jsonString});
});`
The console is showing me jsonString, but how do I "show" the data here http://localhost:8080/tl here is my TL.jade `
extend layout

block content
  div(id='data')
    pre
      test = jsonString`

Comment: How exactly are you making the post request to that route? If you are visiting `localhost:8080/tl` it never actually makes a post request to `localhost:8080/` which is where you will see the JSON according to the code above... Can you update the question to clearly define what is expected behaviour?

Comment: Ok I have updated, could you please take a look? Basically I want it to show on my local website, I mean I see it in my node command prompt, but I dont see it on my localwebsite

Comment: One more thing, you asked how I make that post request. I make it from other website in my google chrome browser, for example I make the post request (my javascript code) on http://example.com and Im trying to send the array of data from there to my node and render it on my local website. I came to the point where I see the data in my node (via console.log(req.body)) but I cant make it show me it in my index.jade..

Comment: Can you share the code you use to make the post request? If you visit `localhost:8080/` you will be making a GET request, not POST.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the data in the template.

```
res.render('index', {data: 'data'});
```

And show it with:

```
data = data
    p #{data}
```

Comment: where do I put res.render? Inside app.post('/', function(){}) ?? Whenever I put 'data' inside my jade file it says 'data is undefined' but I see it in console log

Comment: @Bolo `POST` is for submitting data. `GET` is for retrieving data from a server. The `res.render` should always go in the `app.get` route.

Comment: ok mate, tell me how do I render the data I get from my post from another website? do I have to reload my localwebsite, put some submit button or something? Im noob at this trying to figure it out since yesterday..

Comment: @Bolo Let's say you have a TODO list app. The TODO list input form is rendered on `app.get("/")`, which upon submission sends a `POST` request to `app.get("/todos")`. The code in this route saves the data to a variable, or in a database. After that, when you refresh the `app.get("/")`, it sends a `GET` request to `app.get("/todos")` to get a JSON response with the list of todos (from the database), and you then display the data however you want. I suggest you read more on `RESTful APIs`.

Answer (score 0):

First you should parse your incoming data, as is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. You'll need to `JSON.parse` req.body first and encode your response as json too

```
app.post("/", function (req, res) {
  var  response = try { JSON.parse(req.body) } catch(e) { console.error('Invalid Data') };
  res.json(response || {});
});
```

You could also send your data as 'application/json' from you client JS and save receive a JSON directly to the `req.body`.

Hope it helps

*UPDATE* (if you want to append new data via async requests on the client)

In this [post](https://www.carnaghan.com/2016/10/using-jquery-ajax-to-retrieve-sample-json-data/) you can see the use of `XmlHttpRequest` with `jquery $.ajax()` which is basically the same concept of async requests after the DOM is rendered on your server.

Imagine the step 3 being your Jade rendered HTML

Comment: I see the data I send from the website to my node server in console log but how do I actually show the data in m index.jade??

Comment: I think you're mixin up concepts here.
On one side, you have Jade, which is a server side rendered template framework

On the other side, you want to do an async POST call to an endpoint on your express server to retrieve JSON data

If you want your data directly rendered into Jade, you will need to embed the data into the template variables before rendering it

If you want to an async call once the Jade is already rendered, you will need to handle the `XMLHttpRequest` callback, and use native javascript, jquery or whatever you want to append the new data in the DOM elements

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just putting the data into the sqlite3 database and then retrieving the data via GET request and finally putting it into my jade template. I thought I can go around and not use sqlite3 but I couldnt figure out how.

Here is the code

```
app.post("/", function (req, res) {
  var jsonString = JSON.stringify(req.body || {});
  db.serialize(function () {
    var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO movies (id, title, seed, url) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
    for (var i = 0; i < req.body.length; i++) {
      var d = new Date();
      var data = req.body;
      var n = d.toLocaleTimeString();
      stmt.run(i, req.body[i].title, req.body[i].seed, req.body[i].url);
    }
    stmt.finalize();
  });
  res.send('You sent: this to Express');
});
```

Retrieving the data from the database

```
app.get('/tl', function (req, res, next) {
  db.all('select * from movies', function (err, rows) {
    if (err)
      return next(err);
    var dataO = [];
    rows.forEach(function (row) {
      dataO.push(row);
    })
    res.render('tl', { dataO: dataO });
  })
})
```